# jquery.colorbox.js slideshow too slow

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Jquery.colorbox.js slideshow image loading times has slowed considerably on my site.  Used to load much faster.  Any thoughts as to why and how to mitigate?

Used to load without delay.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../colorbox.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.colorbox.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".winter1819").colorbox({rel:'winter1819'});
});
</script>
```

Pls visit the following - http://sverdina.com/blog.asp & click the image for top blog post (winter 18/19).  Note slow image loading.  Subsequent images not previously loaded/cached in slider all load slowly as well.

Comment: Are you certain that it's a jQuery / Colorbox issue, and not a network or server issue?  Have you measured load times of the actual files?  It's much more likely to be an issue with the host than the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a quick test on your site and watched as the page and files loaded.  The issue is that the server is taking quite a long time to respond.  Here's an example:

[image: image download network timings]

As you can see, nearly all the time is in the content download section.  I'd have a discussion with your hosting provider about this.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  My first thought was that it has something to do with the host/server, being that the images previously loaded much faster all else being the same.  Of course they're denying it has anything to do with their server.  If they keep stonewalling I guess it's time to start shopping...